# Summing two different series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was wondering how to sum the first n terms of the following series:

$1, 1/2, 1/4, 1/4, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8,\ldots$

$1, 1/2, 1/2, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/4, 1/8,\ldots$

I am trying to find a tight bound for the sum of the harmonic series, and the first series is the lower bound and the second series is the upper bound.

I know the first is $(1/2) {\log_2 n}+1$, and the second is ${\log_2 (n+1)}$ just by inspection, but I'm unsure how to do this formally.

Comment: What is your objective?  Your bounds will be at least $1/4$ apart after the third term, so will not be tight.  Your lower bound shows that the series diverges.  If you are trying to evaluate the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) you need a different approach.

Comment: @RossMillikan I can show that the former series (n terms) sums to(1/2)log2n+1 and the latter to log2(n+1), the former of which is smaller than the sum of the harmonic series and the latter of which is larger. Doesn't this show big theta of log n?

Comment: Yes, it shows big theta, but you hadn't talked about that before.  When you said a tight bound I thought you wanted better than that, like showing the sum was close to $\log n + \gamma$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** : For the first series...

Notice that for each $ k\in \mathbb{N} $, $ 2^{k} $th partial sum, $$ S_{2^{k}}= 1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\left( \dfrac{1}{2^{2}}+\dfrac{1}{2^{2}}\right) +...+\left( \dfrac{1}{2^{k}}+...+\dfrac{1}{2^{k}}\right) $$ where in this summation there are $ 2^{k-1} $ number of $ \dfrac{1}{2^{k}} $'s. 
Therefore $ S_{2^{k}}=1+\dfrac{k}{2} $.

Hence $ S_{2^{k}+j}=1+\dfrac{k}{2}+\dfrac{j}{2^{k+1}} $ where $ 0\leq j <2^{k} $ (Eq 1).

Also notice that for each $ n\in \mathbb{N} $, there exist unique $ k\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\} $ and $ 0\leq j <2^{k} $ such that $ n=2^{k}+j $ (Eq 2).

Now use (Eq 1) and (Eq 2).